# 500 internal server error when I hit webserver

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Can anybody help me? My web service is giving me an error.

> 500 Internal Server Error`and`304 Not Modified`

This will return me the XML data. I am unable to get the body of the requested data.

```
 var soapMessage ='<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <soap:Body>    <HelloWorld xmlns="http://5.79.57.16:8095/" />  </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>' ;

$j.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.lsbo.co.uk:8095/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld',
        type: "POST",
        data: soapMessage,
        dataType: "xml",
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        statusCode: {
            200: function () {
                if (304 == jqxhr.status)
                    alert("not modified"); // does not fire
            }
        },
        error: function (responseData) {
            alert("Error:  " + jQuery.parseXML(responseData));
        },
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert("Hye Successfull");
    });
```

Comment: Looks like a cross domain request. You might have to use `jsonp` in such cases

Comment: Error 500 is comming from the server-side, can't do anything with JavaScript code.

Comment: Well, what do you expect, if you *hit* web services?

Comment: seems the server can't identify the `url`. You may be giving wrong url, might be a small typo.

Comment: `304` is not an error, it just means that the content hasn't been modified since the last time you requested the same resource.

Answer (score 0):

500 is an internal service error. My guess is that you are sending the server some data other than what is expecting. Your Ajax request looks ok at first glance. I would set a break point on your service in debugging and see what data it is exactly getting and if it is different from what it is expecting.